# How can I reference instances of two classes?

Tags: java, class, object, reference, instance

I have two classes, say Class A and Class B.

For Class B, it uses the Instance Variables of Class A.

For instance, in Class A:

```
public ClassA {
    numA = 0;
    characterA = 'x';
}
```

Then, when creating an object of ClassB, I need to use the num and character info.

For instance, in Class B:

```
public ClassB {
    ClassA obj = new ClassA();
    numB = obj.getNumA();
    characterB = obj.getCharacterA;
}
```

The problem is, if I change the characterA to 'o' using setCharacterA('o'), the value (i.e. characterB) will not be updated in ClassB.

Is there a way where I can update the value in ClassB also, by using setters in ClassA?

Comment: You need setters in both classes.  The setters in `B` will act on the `A` object in `B`

Comment: You are creating a new instance of ClassA in ClassB. Just because for another instance you changed the value, doesn't mean that change is applied to this instance, so it will always be 'x'. If you want a variable to be changed for all instances, you should make that variable static

Comment: `characterA` seems to be a `char` which is a primitive. `get`ting it will copy the value, not a reference. You could implement a Holder class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an instance of `ClassA` in `ClassB`.

If your code is something like:

```java
ClassA a = new ClassA();
ClassB b = new ClassB();
a.setCharacterA('y');
```

Then, the character of `ClassA` in `ClassB` won't change since there are two different instances. What you need to do is to pass the instance of `ClassA` in `ClassB` via constructor or a setter, such as:

```java
public ClassB {
    private ClassA obj;

    public ClassB(ClassA obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }
}
```

then you can use them as follows:

```java
ClassA a = new ClassA();
ClassB b = new ClassB(a);
a.setCharacterA('y');
```

Now, the character change will also reflect in `ClassB` since you will use the same instance.